# Converter CSV para XLSX com Python Azure Function App

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, microsoft-azure

estou tentando criar uma FunctionApp na Azure para converter um arquivo csv para xlsx.

Meu script original que funciona no windows local é este:

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv ('C:/TEMP/Arquivo.csv')

read_file.to_excel ('C:/TEMP/Arquivo.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Na Azure, estou tentando via HttpTrigger, fazendo o download do arquivo blob do blob storage (arquivo.csv) mas sem sucesso na hora da escrita do xlsx. Não sei onde setar o caminho para a escrita deste.

Agradeço qlqr contribuição.